# Default Argument for Function Template not working

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, default-arguments

I have a function that prints out value_one if it is greater than or less value_two based on the comparison passed through.

```
template<typename T, typename cmp = less<T> >
void function(T value_one, T value_two, cmp) {
    cmp comparator;
    if (comparator(value_one, value_two)) {
        std::cout << value_one;
    }
}
```

Now, this function defaults to using the less function object to decide to print value_one out or not, but can also use the more function object.

```
template<typename T>
class more {
public:
    bool operator()(const T& value_one, const T& value_two) {
        return value_one > value_two;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class less{
public:
    bool operator()(const T& value_one, const T& value_two) {
        return value_one < value_two;
    }
};
```

when i call the following code in main

```
more<int> a;
function(7,5,a);
```

7 is printed out as expected but the next code is deemed illegal, and VS tells me that no matching overloaded function can be found.

```
function(5,7);
```

I thought that the cmp function object would default to less when not explicitly provided and thus would still be able to work. Why does this not work? Is there a way to make this code work without overloading it to just have two parameters?

Answer (score 6):

You have defaulted the **type** `cmp`, but not the argument of the function. In fact, you have not given it any name.

You also need to provide a default for the argument:

```
template<typename T, typename cmp = less<T> >
void function(T value_one, T value_two, cmp = {}) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Provide a default-constructed instance of `cmp` as the default argument